# How to register for BLE state notification in IONIC 2

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

As mentioned in git of BLE for IONIC 2 we can register for BLE enable or disable state : https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#startstatenotifications  . But It gives me error Property `startStateNotification` does not exist on type of BLE. My code is :

```
ble.startStateNotifications(
function(state) {
    console.log("Bluetooth is " + state);
});
```

What I am missing here.I want success and failer both callbacks as well.  Please provide solution..

Comment: I would suggest to also post your issue directly at the github page. (At the top, there is an `Issues` tab) The author will be able to help you directly. Or you can search for similar issues there also

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the plugin through

`import {ble} from ionic-native` is it?

If you take a look at the files in ionic-native>dist>plugins>ble.js, there are a list of commands provided. Check if there is a command called `startStateNotifications`.

> Property startStateNotification does not exist on type of BLE

This would most likely mean ble does not have this function.

You have to check if `ionic-native` is using the latest version of `cordova-plugin-ble-central`.

---

**UPDATE**

Instead of importing through ionic-native, you can import the plugin by running this command in command prompt:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central`

Afterwards, you will use this as a plugin. So just call `ble.startStateNotification()` You will not need to include `import {ble} from ionic-native` already.

I prefer directly importing `cordova-plugin-ble-central` from the main author instead of going through `ionic-native` to call `cordova-plugin-ble-central`. In the event of any updates from the plugin, you can update immediately. Else, you will have to wait on `ionic-native`

Comment: Yes I am importing from ionic-native.So how to check that ionic-native is using the latest version of cordova-lugin?

Comment: I have checked version and its showing 1.1.4. Is it ok? or need to update? If need to update then do u know how to update only ble plugin?

Comment: Also I have checked ble.js there is no command called startStateNotifications.

Comment: I have updated my answer after you confirm there is no startStateNotifications command

Comment: Its saying : Plugin "cordova-plugin-ble-central" already installed on android.
Plugin "cordova-plugin-ble-central" already installed on ios. So now how to import and use directly from that? If I remove that native import statement it gives me error and also writing this: ble.startStateNotification() is giving me error.

Comment: You can try removing the plugin first: `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ble-central` then add it again. What version of ionic 2 are you using?

Comment: I did all you have suggested but no luck

Comment: Check version:
 Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 ,
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.5,
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1,
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0,
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0 ,
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 ,
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 ,
OS: OS X El Capitan ,
Node Version: v7.3.0.